# Why isn't reste framework serializer saving these into two different models

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want serializer to save data to 2 different models:

```
from .models import Url1, Url2



class RushSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    u2 = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Url1       
        fields = ('keyword', 'u1', 'keyword2', 'u2')
```

And here are models:

```
class Url1(models.Model):
    keyword = models.ForeignKey(KW)
    u1 = models.URLField()

class Url2(models.Model):
    keyword2 = models.ForeignKey(KW)
    u2 = models.URLField()
```

And the dict I am trying to save:

```
{"keyword": 73, "u1": "https://www.pinterest.com/ercamacho/diy-headbands/",
  "keyword2": 71, "u2": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9TWxSufCgvE"}
```

Works great if I try to save to just one model but I'd like data to be saved in multiple models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two models, so use `serializers.Serializer` and override `save()`:

```
class RushSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    keyword = ...
    u1 = ...
    keyword2 = ...
    u2 = ...

    def save(self):
        keyword = self.validated_data['keyword']
        u1 = self.validated_data['u1']
        keyword2 = self.validated_data['keyword2']
        u2 = self.validated_data['u2']

        Url1.objects.create(keyword=keyword, u1=u1)
        Url2.objects.create(keyword2=keyword2, u2=u2)
```

See http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances